# Wether there is a document state that the page changes, but the Element will not change?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I have a example about Chrome-console:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="form-input" value="value01" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed the `<input>`'s value to `value012`:

You can see in the console, the value is changed:

```
> var form_input = document.querySelector('[name=form-input]')
< undefined
> form_input

< <input type=​"text" name=​"form-input" value=​"value01">​
> form_input.value

< "value012"
```

But in the Element, the `<input>` did not change.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have a question about it, whether the Element will not change, when I change the page? is there a document state that?

(ingnore the `this will never change:abc`, that's uninfluential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` **property** represents the **current** value.

The `value` **attribute** represents the **default** value. It maps onto the `defaultValue` property.

Modifying the current value doesn't change the default value.

If you had a reset button, it would replace the current value with the default value.

Comment: `<input type="reset">`

Comment: So, you mean I change the <input> value in the page, it is changed by javascript, not the HTML ? Its just store temporarily in the javascript object?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your last comment. There are at least two things called "value", and if you change something then you should know if you used JS to do it or not.

Comment: OK, one more question, you mean the Element is show the document attribute, right?

Comment: The DOM inspector in the browser shows the attributes on the element in the "rendered as HTML" view.